# How to properly install mypy inside a .venv and configure a tests framework | VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, mypy

mypy is installed both globally(using `pip install mypy`) and locally(using Poetry's `[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]` inside my projects root folder.

Here's a tree of the root folder

```
project_root_folder
│
│   poetry.lock
│   pyproject.toml
├───.mypy_cache
│
├───.venv
│
├───.vscode
│
├───tests
│
└───project_folder
```

---

Partial problem :

- While **NOT** in a virtual environment, if I use `mypy --version` I get :

"pytest: The term 'pytest' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again."

- While **inside an activated** .venv, if I use `mypy --version` :

It successfully reports mypy's version. In this case it was installed with `poetry install` as a dev dependency using a `pyproject.toml`

---

Main Problem :

Even though `Python: Select Linter` finds mypy and it successfully creates a .mypy_cache inside my root folder, when I try to `Python: Configure Tests` there is no mypy framework/tool

[image]

---

TLDR

1. How can I properly configure the framework of my tests folder to
   work with mypy?
2. Why `where.exe mypy` and `mypy --version` don't work outside the
   virtual environment?

Answer (score 1):

**First Problem:**

Sorry, the Python extension built-in three types of test:

> Testing: Run and debug tests through the Test Explorer with unittest,
> pytest or nose

You can check it from the [official docs](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python#feature-details).

There's no `mypy` test framework.

**Second One:**

When you activate the virtual environment, the value of the system environments was changed, you can check it through `sys.path`.

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```